# How do I avoid `<style>` tags getting caught in my CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm using CSS to style some existing documents, and using a lot of adjacent sibling selectors (e.g. item1 + item2) to apply spacing, etc. between elements. However, many of the documents also include `<style>` tags at the top of the page, or scattered throughout where custom styling has been applied. The custom styling itself is fine, but unfortunately the `<style>` tags themselves are interfering with my CSS selectors. For example, if I want to apply a `margin-top` to every element except the first, I would usually use `* + *` (aka, the ["lobotomized owl"](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls/) approach), and this works great UNTIL somebody puts a style tag at the top. Now the *style tag* is being read as the first element, and so EVERY element on the page is being selected. I do not know the element types in advance; they can be any combination of valid HTML code (div, span, p, table, etc...) and need to account for nested elements t as well. The key selector I am trying to fix is the adjacent sibling selector starting with a wildcard ( `* + item`).

Using something like `:not(style) + item` was my first thought, but then if there are any `<style>` tags in the middle of the page somewhere, any element after one of those will be styled incorrectly as well.

Is there a surefire way of doing this purely with CSS? I am not able to edit the HTML files themselves, but might be able to pre-process them with Javascript before they are rendered if I have to.

**Edit:** Bonus question, how do I select the first element in the page that is *not* a `<style>` tag? I.e, how do I now do `body > *:first-child` without selecting a `<style>` tag?

For example, my CSS file and then a target HTML:

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

*+div {
  background-color: lime;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<style>
  div {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<div>Yellow</div>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Green</div>
<div>Green</div>
```

Comment: I just realized that if you only need to worry about lobotomized owls, then it's possible my entire answer could be replaced with `:not(body):not(style):nth-child(n+2)`, which is robust to any number of element types. For a more focused answer I recommend specifying exactly what selectors you want replaced (e.g. do you only need to worry about children of body? What about nested elements?). My answer is currently trying a little too hard to cover a variety of cases.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. I need to handle any combination of valid HTML. Some places I am adding spaces between paragraphs and tables `p + table` or some places I am spacing out lists and divs. It's from a set of 1,000+ documents so it could be just about anything. I also would prefer to have a general `* + *` as a base style to reduce the number of special case permutations I need to type out.

Comment: And as my edit says, I'm also looking to replace `body > *:first-child` to somehow select the first element in the body, but ignoring any `<style>` tags.

Comment: I'm not too happy with my answer so I'll be deleting it and replacing it with a new one.

Comment: Go for it. I appreciate the help.  I also reread your comment and further updated my question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Margins can get complicated as document layouts get more complex, but for simplicity's sake this answer will assume you only have to worry about lobotomized owls, and documents with relatively simple block layouts in which margins collapse between parents and children, so we can focus on the selectors at hand.

The following selector is robust to any number of element types and any nesting depth (i.e. not just children of `body`). Unfortunately it does involve repeating the same compound selector:

```css
div, p {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0; /* Remove default p margins for the sake of illustration */
}

:not(style):nth-of-type(n+2),
:not(style):nth-of-type(n+2) ~ * {
  background-color: lime;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* Ignore .nest elements for the sake of illustration */
.nest {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<style>
  div {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<div>Yellow</div>
<div>Green</div>
<p>Green</p>

<style>
  p {
    font-style: italic;
  }
</style>

<div>Green</div>
<p>Green</p>

<section class="nest">
  <div>Yellow</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <p>Green</p>
</section>
```

> Bonus question, how do I select the first element in the page that is *not* a `<style>` tag? I.e, how do I now do `body > *:first-child` without selecting a `<style>` tag?

Assuming there will never be more than one `style` element before the first non-`style` child:

```css
body > :not(style):first-child, body > style:first-child + *
```

If you think there may be documents with more than one consecutive `style` as the first children of `body`, you'll need to use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) instead:

```css
body > :not(style) {
  /* Apply styles to the first non-style child */
}

body > :not(style) ~ :not(style) {
  /* Undo the above styles for following non-style children */
}
```

There isn't a selector-based alternative that's robust until browsers start implementing level 4 `:nth-child(An+B of S)`:

```css
/* Replaces the main answer's entire selector-list */
:nth-child(n+2 of :not(body, style))

/* Replaces the bonus question's answer */
body > :nth-child(1 of :not(style))
```